# Enter date data type from user

Tags: c, date, input

I am faced with a problem that i want user to enter the date .The date entered by user can be of any format eg. `dd-mm-yy` , `dd-mm-yyyy` ,`dd-month-yy`. I can think of only 2 ways to do it.

1.Using structures. But the date format is not specified.

2.Using `sscanf()` and `sprintf()` function to copy as string and then obtaining invidual values using sscanf() function.

Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest [and probably the *safest*] way to achieve this is to

1. take the input as string using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
2. tokenize the string tusing [`strtok_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r), using the `.`, `-`, `/` as delimiter, and probably the [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) to differenciate between `dd`, `mm` and `yyyy`.
3. convert the strings to inegers using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) ans store accordingly.

<sup>Needless to mention, don't forget to validate the data afterwards.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use strtok() as shown below and you can get the entered date in any of the formats mentioned in your question.

```
 int main()
    {
       char *p; 
       char a[20];
       printf("ENter date:\n");
       scanf("%s",a);

       p = strtok(a,"-");
       while( p  != NULL)
       {   
          printf("%s ",p);/* I am printing here you can do what even you want to */
          p = strtok(NULL,"-");
       }   
    }
```

Comment: Thx,can u explain the last line p=strtok(NULL,"-");

Comment: strtok() maintains a internal state so once you pass proper string value to this function later on just pass NULL and the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna be the devils advocate here and recommend writing a simple parser.

Let's look at the formats and see what we're going to be accepting:

- A day (01 to 31)
- A month (01 to 12 or 'January' to 'December")
- A year (70-99 and 00-16 or 1970 to 2016)

Below is something I just slapped together as an example

```
#include <ctype.h>   // isalpha, isdigit
#include <string.h>  // strncmp

struct DATE {
    int day, month, year;
};

// return 1 on success, else 0 on failure
int readdate(DATE *date, char *text) {
    int toklen = 0;
    char *tokval;
    if (isdigit(*text)) {      // expect a number for the day
        date->day = *text++ - '0';
        if (isdigit(*text))    // accept another number
            date->day = date->day * 10 + *text++ - '0';
        if (date->day < 1 || date->day > 31)
            return 0;
    } else return 0;
    if (*text == '-')          // expect a hyphen
        text++;
    else
        return 0;
    if (isdigit(*text)) {      // accept a number for the month...
        date->month = *text++ - '0';
        if (isdigit(*text))    // accept another number
            date->month = date->month * 10 + *text++ - '0';
        if (date->month == 0 || date->month > 12)
            return 0;
    } else if (isalpha(*text)) {
        tokval = text;         // accept a word
        do {
            toklen++;
            text++:
        } while (isalpha(*text));
        /* expect that the word is a name of a month */
        if (!strncmp("january", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 1;
        else if (!strncmp("february", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 2;
        else if (!strncmp("march", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 3;
        else if (!strncmp("april", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 4;
        else if (!strncmp("may", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 5;
        else if (!strncmp("june", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 6;
        else if (!strncmp("july", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 7;
        else if (!strcmp("august", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 8;
        else if (!strcmp("september", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 9;
        else if (!strcmp("october", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 10;
        else if (!strcmp("november", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 11;
        else if (!strcmp("december", tokval, toklen))
            date->month = 12;
        else
            return 0;
    } else return 0;
    if (*text == '-')        // expect a hyphen
        text++;
    else
        return 0;
    if (isdigit(*text)) {           // expect a number
        date->year = *text++ - '0';
        if (isdigit(*text)) {       // expect another number
            date->year = date->year * 10 + *text++ - '0';
            if (isdigit(*text)) {   // accept another number
                date->year = date->year * 10 + *text++ - '0';
                if (isdigit(*text)) // expect another number
                    date->year = date->year * 10 + *text++ - '0';
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        } else return 0;
        /* ensure the year fits a valid range */
        if (date->year >= 70 && date->year <= 99)
            date->year += 1900;
        else if (date->year < 70)
            date->year += 2000;
        if (date->year < 1970 || date->year > 2070)
            return 0;
    } else return 0;
/*
 * you can do some optional checking on the date here to verify if the
 * day of the month is valid here
 */
    return 1;
}
```

When you start getting into dealing with multiple string formats, it's often easier and more manageable in the long run to just write a simple parser. But that's just my 2 cents.